# Can't eject disk after creating image

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I am running the latest software. This is a fresh install of Mac OS X 10.8.* latest. I am on a Macbook6,1. I am using my internal optical drive installed in a external enclosure(from OWC) after installing another drive in place of the optical drive internally. The external enclosure is USB 2 with two type A connectors for sufficient power. Everything works great, but when I create a disk image from the optical media in Disk Utility, everything works as expected, but once finished, the disk is greyed out and shown as not mounted, but when trying to eject it, I always get the error that it's in use and can't be ejected. To solve this, I have to close and open Disk Utility and everything works. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue....IMO just restarting Disk Utility is as much of a Solution as Im looking for....thanks for the ....half answer with the question....

Comment: Same problem... MB Air mid-2011, OS X 10.9.5, Amazon Basics external DVD drive.  Annoying!  Happens 100% of time, restart fixes 100% of time.